# Reusable android styles?

Tags: android, themes, android-styles

I can't seem to be able to find any existing android styles. 
Are there no resources out there that provide free reusable Android Development styles?

All I can find are tutorials for theming and this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html.

I am thinking of CSS templates... Why reinvent the wheel when someone already made a beautiful style?

Comment: I think that I may have confused "themes" with "styles".

Answer (score 2):

Its generally a good idea to stay mostly within the design guidelines Android has set up for us, so that users have an easier time learning how to use your app by providing a familiar environment. A good way to differentiate your app from others is by tinkering with the colors used in your themes, and the following tools can generate new themes for you:

For general app themeing:
http://android-holo-colors.com/

For styling the actionbar:
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: The first link is broken .

Comment: I don't know why, it was up just a couple days ago. Perhaps the creator is just doing some maintenance, or he forgot to pay for the domain this month, I'm not sure what's going on. But in the meantime, this tool exists as a plugin for the IntelliJ/Android Studio IDE, and you can download that here: https://github.com/jeromevdl/android-holo-colors-idea-plugin

Answer (score -1):

Don't you want instead to comply with the existing themes as this way your app will always be well aligned with the most current Android UI style?

Comment: The current theme when used with the default UI control is very lackluster and plain looking...

Comment: It's not a question of aesthetics at all

Comment: Typical "why do you wanna do that?" SO answer.